# Connecting Microsoft Band SDK Preview to C++ project

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone, c++-cx, win-universal-app, microsoft-band

I have just downloaded the Microsoft Band SDK Preview and trying to connect it to my C++/CX Windows Universal App project. Nuget gives me an error below, any way I could use the SDK preview from C++ code?

```
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.Band 1.3.10219-preview'. 
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Native,Version=v0.0', 
but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are 
compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
 + Install-Package Microsoft.Band -Pre
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

It seems the problem is generic to installing managed assemblies to C++ projects, but I haven't managed to find the workaround yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Band SDK Preview (1.3.10219-preview) NuGet package does not specifically target Windows Runtime Components, which means it cannot be consumed (directly) by C++ or JavaScript Windows Runtime Component libraries. As an alternative, you could create a Windows Runtime Component library (C# or VB) that wraps the portion of the Band SDK you need and then consume that library from your C++ or JavaScript component.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, please consider adding a native WinRT component into the later releases.

Comment: Yikes. Why wouldn't this be built as a WinRT Component? This is likely why I've been unable to install the SDK Preview to try it out with Tweetium (which is HTML/JS/C++). Sort of the whole point of WinRT components was to enable libraries like this one to extend the platform naturally (without dependencies on specific frameworks like .NET).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the Band SDK is only for VB.NET and C# projects - I've tried getting it for a WP JavaScript application, but I ran across the same problem that you are having.

I haven't seen anything from Microsoft or anyone else about this issue. Perhaps since the JS / C++ projects aren't 100% managed languages (there's native C++ and Visual C++ [managed]), it doesn't support them (correct me if I'm wrong, I don't know much about the internals). Hopefully in a future release.

Comment: Well this is what I think - but on the other hand, there might be a way as 'managed' and 'native' are mixed in quite a complicated way in WinRT - and the Band SDK might define a Windows Runtime Component that can be consumed from C++ or JS app. Maybe someone from Microsoft can comment..